# Agrupacion y suma kendo grid

Tags: c#, jquery, mvc, kendoui

buenas gente alguno podria indicarme como puedo hacer para sumar y agrupar resultados con kendo grid y jquery? el ejemplo exacto es hacer esto
[Codigo ejemplo kendo grid jquery agrupacion y suma de totales](https://dojo.telerik.com/EmaSIZaT)

mi problema es que la manera en que yo cargo mis kendo grid es distinta a la del ejemplo ya que hago una llamada con ajax y cuando termina y me trae la lista yo cargo mi kendo de la siguiente manera:

```
  _settings.kendoGrid.ActivosDepreciacion.dataSource = [];  
  _settings.kendoGrid.ActivosDepreciacion.dataSource = json.value.data.ActivosDepreciacion;
  $.fillKendoGrid(_settings.kendoGrid.ActivosDepreciacion);
```

y la definicion o estructura de mi kendo grid es de la siguiente manera:

```
   var _settings = {
    host: "", 
    area: "IA/",
    wa: {//NOMBRE DE LOS CONTROLADORES QUE SERÁN UTILIZADOS EN ESTE JS
        Asa_EstudioTarifario: "Asa_EstudioTarifario/",
        Asa_EstudioTarifario_Paso3_Inversiones: "Asa_EstudioTarifario_Paso3_Inversiones/"
    },
    sesion: {}, 
    appSettings: {},     
    dataSource: {},
    dropDownList: {},
    kendoGrid: {
                ActivosLista: {
            //CONFIGURACIÓN DEL KENDOGRID
            selector: "#grdActivosLista",
            height: "300px",
            url: "", //EL URL FINAL SE ARMA EN EL MÉTODO DE INICIALIZACIÓN DE LA CLASE
            columns: [ //COLUMNAS QUE TENDRÁ EL GRID
                { field: "id_FinancieroInversionesDepreciacionActivo", title: "id_FinancieroInversionesDepreciacionActivo", hidden: true },
                { field: "id_FinancieroInversionesEncabezado", title: "id_FinancieroInversionesEncabezado", hidden: true },
                { field: "id_FinancieroInversionesDetalle", title: "id_FinancieroInversionesDetalle", hidden: true },
                { field: "id_TipoInversiones", title: "Tipo inversion", hidden: true },
                { field: "precioUnitario", title: "PrecioUnitario", hidden: true },
                { field: "cantidad", title: "Cantidad", hidden: true },
                { field: "anho", title: "anho", width: "300px", hidden: true },
                { field: "descripcion", title: "Activo", width: "300px",footerTemplate: "Total General "  },
                
                { field: "anho1", title: "anho1", format: "{0:N2}", type: "number", headerTemplate: createHeaderTemplate('anho1')},
                { field: "anho2", title: "anho2", format: "{0:N2}", type: "number", headerTemplate: createHeaderTemplate('anho2') },
                { field: "anho3", title: "anho3", format: "{0:N2}", type: "number", headerTemplate: createHeaderTemplate('anho3') },
                { field: "anho4", title: "anho4", format: "{0:N2}", type: "number", headerTemplate: createHeaderTemplate('anho4') },
                { field: "anho5", title: "anho5", format: "{0:N2}", type: "number", headerTemplate: createHeaderTemplate('anho5') },  
                {
                    field: "Acciones", title: "Acciones",
                    width: "100px",
                    filterable: false,
                    template: "<div style=\"text-align: left;\">\
                                           <a class=\"InactivaInversion\" role=\"button\" ><u><font color=\"blue\">Eliminar</font></u></a>\
                                </div>"
                },
            ],
            editable: false,
            pageable: { //ESTA CONFIGURACIÓN PERMITE MEJORAR EL PERFORMANCE DEL GRID PARA GRANDES CANTIDADES DE REGISTROS
                numeric: true,
                previousNext: true,
                messages: {
                    display: "Total: {2} registro(s)"
                },
                pageSize: 500,
            },
            resizable: true
        },
      popup: {},//CONFIGURACIÓN DE POPUPS      
};
```

por lo que noto que en el ejemplo que comparti en el link de arriba, se hace una configuración del datasource, pero en mi caso el datasource ya viene configurado automáticamente y no puedo hacer agrupaciones ni agregaciones ya que me tira un error al hacer la suma como si no detectara el formato numerico de las columnas que estoy sumando. claramente en el codigo que acabo de compartir no estoy haciendo la agrupacion, pero lo que necesito saber es como puedo cargar el datasource para lograr lo del ejemplo del link?

este seria el error que me genera al hacer la suma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

probe la recomendacion de editar el datasource y cree esta estructura:

```
'var dataSource1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        data: $.parseJSON(json.value.data.InversionesLista.Content),
                             schema: {
                            model: {
                                fields: {
                                    descripcion: { type: "string" },
                                    anho1: { type: "number" },
                                    anho2: { type: "number" },
                                    anho3: { type: "number" },
                                    anho4: { type: "number" },
                                    anho5: { type: "number" }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        aggregate: [
                            { field: "descripcion", aggregate: "count" },
                            { field: "anho1", aggregate: "sum" },
                            { field: "anho2", aggregate: "sum" },
                            { field: "anho3", aggregate: "sum" },
                            { field: "anho4", aggregate: "sum" },
                            { field: "anho5", aggregate: "sum" }
                        ]
                    });'
```

y para cargar el grid estoy usando la linea, pero no me carga nada apezar de que los datos si llegan en un formato json valido,`$("#grdActivosLista").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(dataSource1);'.
que podra ser?

Answer (score 0):

Define el `DataSource` usando algo como esto

```
 var dataSource1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    data: $.parseJSON(json.value.data.ActivosDepreciacion),
                    aggregate: [{ field: "cantidad", aggregate: "sum" }]
                });
```

[kendogrid aggregate on dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249553/kendogrid-aggregate-on-dynamic-columns)

No se si lo que obtienes en `json.value` ya es un json valido o si debes parsearlo, esto puede probarlo.

Puedes definir en el `aggregate` las columnas que quieres que se muestren sumadas, pudiendo cambiar esto cuando asignas el datasource

Para asignarlo usarias

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(dataSource1);
```

como veras en este ejemplo

[link codigo](http://jsbin.com/irohuc/6/edit)

Comment: los datos de esta linea json.value.data.ActivosDepreciacion  es un array creado con linq, al hacer el $.parseJSON(json.value.data.ActivosDepreciacion) me da el error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 y no me carga los datos, le quite el agregate y el paseJSON y tampoco me carga el grid, no comprendo por que cargando el array directo al datasource no me da problema que podra ser?

Comment: bien, pero linq es tecnologia del lado de backend, y json es tecnologia del frontend, una no tiene que ver con la otra sino se puede serializar correctamente. Si usas `console.log(json.value.data.ActivosDepreciacion);` puedes ver en la consola del developer tools del browser un json valido?

Comment: parece que si, me devuelve:  DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost/sct/Styles/Frameworks/kendo.common.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
Asa_EstudioTarifario_Paso3_Inversiones.js:731 [{…}]0: anho: 2020anho1: [1000]0: 1000length: 1__proto__: Array(0)anho2: [0]anho3: [0]0: 0length: 1__proto__: Array(0)anho4: [0]anho5: [0]cantidad: 1descripcion: "ACTIVO1"id_FinancieroInversionesDepreciacionActivo: 58id_FinancieroInversionesDetalle: 105id_FinancieroInversionesEncabezado: 85id_TipoInversiones: 1precioUnitario: 10

Comment: Ese mensaje indica un error de `http 404` o sea que el request al servidor no esta respondiendo, deberias revisar como invocas al servidor para obtener el json de respuesta

Comment: si tienes razón, pero es por otro archivo, pero la estructura si parece un json valido adjunto solo la estructura: `Asa_EstudioTarifario_Paso3_Inversiones.js:731 [{…}]0: anho: 2020anho1: [1000]0: 1000length: 1__proto__: Array(0)anho2: [0]anho3: [0]0: 0length: 1__proto__: Array(0)anho4: [0]anho5: [0]cantidad: 1descripcion: "ACTIVO1"id_FinancieroInversionesDepreciacionActivo: 58id_FinancieroInversionesDetalle: 105id_FinancieroInversionesEncabezado: 85id_TipoInversiones: 1precioUnitario: 1000__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)`

Comment: cual es el json valido? estara dentro de `[{…}]` porque el resto no es ningun json. Debes asegurarte que `json.value.data.ActivosDepreciacion` es realmente un json, sino no va a funcionar

Comment: '[{"id_FinancieroInversionesDepreciacionActivo":58,"id_FinancieroInversionesEncabezado":85,"id_FinancieroInversionesDetalle":105,"descripcion":"ACTIVO1","cantidad":1,"id_TipoInversiones":1,"precioUnitario":1000.00,"anho":2020,"anho1":1000.00,"anho2":0.00,"anho3":0.00,"anho4":0.00,"anho5":0.00},
{"id_FinancieroInversionesDepreciacionActivo":59, "id_FinancieroInversionesEncabezado":86,"id_FinancieroInversionesDetalle":106,"descripcion":"activo2","cantidad":2,"id_TipoInversiones":1,"precioUnitario":1000.00,"anho":2021,"anho1":0.00,"anho2":2000.00,"anho3":0.00,"anho4":0.00,"anho5":0.00}]'

Comment: pero no me muestra nada al cargar el grid con : '$("#grdActivosLista").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(dataSource1);'

Comment: veo que cambiaste a `json.value.data.InversionesLista.Content` ahora estas seguro que el json tiene contenido? mas alla de usar el setDataSource() porque no lo defines de forma estandar con un json de ejecmplo con valores fijos, respectando al estructura que esperas obtener para ver si se visualiza bien el grid, si lo hace despues cambias a los datos que obtienes desde el servidor

Comment: lo que al final hice es montar el ejemplo que hice en Internet en mi proyecto, pero me pasa lo mismo, jala bien la información pero al sumar da error o del todo no muestra los pie de pagina, creo que es por la versión del jquery y del kendo.js, este es el ejemplo:https://dojo.telerik.com/EmaSIZaT/5

Comment: bien ahi veo funciona todo correcto, que pasa si ahora vas cambiando ese codigo usando un json (aunque sea statico) con los items que quieres mostrar, asignas el json a una variable y la usas de datasource. Si eso funciona despues solo es cuestion de pedirla por http

Comment: Usar un aggregate count en ProductName no aplica, es un campo de texto. Ademas ya tienes la cantidad de items en al paginado